# Does Polymorphic Slicing occur when Derived Object declares no New Members

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17

Does slicing occur in polymorphism, if you store a derived class *by value*, **but** the derived class has no extra members?

For example, if I have a class `Base`. But I want a custom constructor, so I implement `Custom`, like so:

```
class Base{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    Base(int a) 
        : a(a) 
    { b = 2; }
};
class Custom : public Base{
public: // Note: no new members or functions!
    Custom(int bb) 
        : Base(1) 
    { b = bb; }
};
```

If I run it with the following code, it all works as it should. The two instances of `Base` is initialized correctly. They

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    Base base = Base(1);
    Base sliced = Custom(2);
    Custom custom = Custom(2);

    // Some printing of `a`, `b`, and sizeof(base), etc
}
```

It prints out the following, as you would expect:

```
         |   a |   b | Size                                                         
-----------------------------
    base |   1 |   2 |   8                                                          
  sliced |   1 |   2 |   8                                                          
  custom |   1 |   2 |   8
```

So, if I could ask more specifically:

1. Will this always work? I.e. will I lose information of `a` or `b`? (any members/functions of `Base`)
2. If not, why not? Does a derived object store extra information?
3. If this will always work, is it bad practice?

I have looked into using `strong types`, as described by [this](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/) blog by FluentCpp. This will also work for my implementation, but I feel this makes the code more bloated.

Comment: *but I feel this makes the code more bloated.* -- Does that mean you never really tested strong types?  One thing I learned -- until you have something to test, in C++, never guess.  I've seen entire functions that do all sorts of things with numbers get reduced down to barely anything by a good optimizing compiler.

Comment: I have implemented it, yes. I'm not sure how the compiler optimizes it, because the speed not essential in my code. When I say bloated I mean, harder to read and more complex to use.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie especially when you start to use `static constexpr`... yeah, it might take a little more time to compile or build, but more than `1/2` your code or generated assembly just "magically" vanishes... and that's even without Optimizations turned on and in debug mode... Turn Optimization to O3 and build and run in release mode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does slicing occur in polymorphism, if you store a derived class by value, but the derived class has no extra members?

Yes.

It's quite another matter that you don't see any significant loses in your posted code. The metrics you are using to compare the objects indicate as though nothing got lost because of object slicing. However, if you look at the objects in a debugger, you will most likley notice that objects are of different types. The effects of object slicing become apparent in that environment.

I would recommend not creating a derived class just for the convenience of constructing an object of the base class. Use of one or more non-member functions is more appropriate.

```
class Base
{
   public:
      int a;
      int b;
      Base(int a, int b = 2) : a(a) , b(b) {}
};

Base fromA(int a)
{
   return {a};
}

Base fromB(int b)
{
   return {1, b};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why I didn't see slicing in my example?

Comment: @HeinWessels, because the derived class does not add anything that adds to the size of the base class. `d - 0 == b` does not imply that `d-0` did not happen.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that no slicing happened? Or does slicing happen on a deeper level?

Comment: @HeinWessels, it happens. Let's say you create `Custom a; Base b = a;`. If you look at those objects in the debugger, the debugger will let you know that `a` is of type `Custom` while `b` is of type `Base`. In that environment, you definitely lose something.

Comment: @RSahu: Slicing means the type "changed" and all extra info was "lost".  The fact that you have no extra information doesn't mean slicing didn't happen, it merely means the slicing didn't have any extra information to "lose".

Comment: @MooingDuck, agree 100 percent.

Comment: I would opt either for constructors or static member functions instead of non-member functions as replacement.

Comment: @valsaysReinstateMonica, `static` member functions would work too. I have a preference for using non-member functions if the needed functionality can be implemented using non-member functions.

Comment: @RSahu so you're saying I will lose `type` information (which I'm okay with), but not any information about the `base`'s members? For example, `a` and `b` will be what `Custom` set them to, even if the object is cast back to `Base`?

Answer (score 2):

Using inheritance for the task that you seem to be using it for is not a good idea. Note that from c++20, you can solve the problem you've shown with designated initializers:

```
class Base 
{
  public:
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
};

int main() 
{
    Base a = Base{.a = 10};  // default b
    Base b = Base{.b = 20};  // default a
    Base c = Base{.a = 10, .b = 20};
}
```

Comment: That is interesting, I will keep a look out for it.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for having derived classes is to have virtual functions. With your code, once the object is sliced, the virtual functions will start calling the base class versions:

https://godbolt.org/z/WoT5qb

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    Base(int a) 
        : a(a) 
    {
        b = 2; 
    }

    virtual void foo()
    {       
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Custom : public Base{
public: // Note: no new members!
    Custom(int bb) 
        : Base(1) 
    { b = bb; }

    virtual void foo()
    {       
        std::cout << "Custom" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Base base = Base(1);
    Base sliced = Custom(2);
    Custom custom = Custom(2);

    base.foo();
    custom.foo();
    sliced.foo();
}
```

which outputs:

```
Base
Custom
Base
```

So, slicing is still very much undesirable.

Comment: I am not going to implement any virtual functions. See the comment `Note: no new members`, which I also meant as no extra functions.

Comment: Fair enough, but your collaborators will most likely be confused by the use of inheritance